# HTML/Python Upload and download a file

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I have a button type ="file", which uploads a file. I'm using Google App Engine.

```
<form action="/sign?%s" method="post">
    <div><br><br>Select a file: <input type="file" value="file"></div>
     <form method="get" action="file">
  <button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible, after choosing a file to display more options (rather than just the file name), for example format and timestamp?
2. I would like to create a download button now, that downloads the file I have uploaded using the above upload button, is there a simple way to do that?